# Windsor Typed factory to create objects with same dependencies as parent

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

My Wpf application has a lot of different view models, that depend on repositories and command factories, registered with a transient lifestyle bound to the view model. Commands are created with a typed factory which will always create new instances of dependencies. That can be a problem because of tracking issues in ORMs when the view model depends on a repository and a command that also depends on that repository.

For that reason I want my command factories to create commands with the same instance of repositories as the view model.

How can this be solved by the container without manually creating factories?

### Edit - Example with runnable code

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly ICommandFactory commandFactory;

    public Service(IRepository repository, ICommandFactory commandFactory)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.commandFactory = commandFactory;
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        repository.SaveChanges();
        commandFactory.Create().Execute();
    }
}

public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand Create();
}

public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public Command(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    void SaveChanges();
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private static int i = 0;
    private int instanceNumber = 0;

    public Repository()
    {
        instanceNumber = i++;
        Console.WriteLine("Created repository nr: " + instanceNumber);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Save changes for repository nr: " + instanceNumber);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<Service>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<Repository>().LifestyleBoundTo<object>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICommand>().ImplementedBy<Command>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICommandFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleTransient());

        var service = container.Resolve<Service>();

        service.DoIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using transient lifestyle for all dependencies, it is obvious that you have different instances of `IRepository` in Service and Command classes. What you need, is to increase lifetime of `IRepository` and probably bind it to lifetime of your service, meaning that the instance of IRepository is created and disposed when the instance of Service is created and disposed.

Castle Windsor has [Bound](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#bound) lifestyle:

> Somewhere in the graph we have two view models, one depending on the other, and both of them depend on some other service, say a repository. You might want to bind the repository to the subgraph. In other words you might want the entire subgraph of the outermost view model (WelcomeScreenViewModel) to share the same instance of the repository, and to have the repository released when the view model itself is released.

So should register your IRepository in the following way:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<Repository>().LifestyleBoundTo<Service>());
```

**EDIT:**
The above solution will not work as ICommand is bound to ICommandFactory not to Service. If you are resolving service instance manually you can use LifestyleScoped:

```
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<Service>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IRepository>().ImplementedBy<Repository>().LifestyleScoped());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICommand>().ImplementedBy<Command>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<ICommandFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleTransient());
        
        using (container.BeginScope())
        {
            var service = container.Resolve<Service>();
            service.DoIt();
        }
```

In this case your IRepository is scoped per scope.

*Note* To use container.BeginScope() add `using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;`

Comment: Hey Andrei. Thank you for your answer. I can't make your solution work. I edited my question and added runnable code. Can you point me in the right direction? Your solution does not work, the factory seems to create all dependencies from scratch. Bound to service throws an error: Scope was not available for 'WindsorTest.Repository'.